# Compute the minimum spanning tree using Prim's algorithm : how to make it simple?

Tags: c++, boost

The issue here is mostly implementation. I'd like to compute a MST using Prim's algorithm.

Here's the code :

```cpp
vector<edge_desc> mst;
auto root = boost::vertex(h, Gs[i]);
boost::prim_minimum_spanning_tree(Gs[i], root);
```

Where `h` is an integer, `Gs` is a vector of weight graphs, defined like so :

```cpp
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS,
                              boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int>>
    weighted_graph;
```

I have this error :

```
no instance of overloaded function "boost::prim_minimum_spanning_tree" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (weighted_graph, std::size_t, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<edge_desc, std::allocator<edge_desc>>>)
```

According to the documentation : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.html

I need to give all of these named parameters?

How does C++ know which parameter is which?

My goal is to construct a MST starting from `root` on `Gs[i]` and store the edge descriptors inside `mst`.

How do I proceed?

Comment: you pass them in correct **order**

Answer (score 4):

"I need to give all of these named parameters?" - Yes.

"How does C++ know which parameter is which?" - By the order in which they are provided.